# rendering radio instead of checkbox or select list in forms

Tags: atk4

I hav a form which has a model as a source:

```
$form->setModel("test");
```

In model, we can define the field type, for example: boolean will make the checkbox in form.
now how can we define the type which be rendered as Radio buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify type in your Model like so

```
$this->addField("name")->setValueList(array('1'=>1, '2'=>2))->type('radio');
```

Comment: Thank U very much but I have another problem. now it automatically adds third option with this title: "Please, select"!!!

Comment: Still exists! the "Please, select" field automatically is added!

Comment: Did you add it to the field in Model?

Comment: Here is an example that works.

In Model
`$this->addField("name")->datatype("string")->setvalueList(array('qwe'=>'qwe','asd'=>'asd'))->type('radio')->mandatory(true);`

On Page
`$m = $this->add('Model_User');
$f = $this->add('Form');
$f->setModel($m);`

Comment: But I do this and again the third option appears in the form :(

Comment: Hi again! I solved it by using this code: $form->getElement("select_sth")->empty_text=""; thank u very much @stakantin.

Comment: Thanks you too. I just forgot about that way.